# HTML5 CSS Designing in Blend or Blend for VS 2012

Tags: blend, blend-2012

I am not much familiar with Win8 app development. VS 2012 Blend is mostly talked about in context of HTML5, CSS Windows 8 app development. 
We are trying to develop a HTML5 based web site with ASP.NET web api backend. I will like to know, is Blend for VS2012 useful as pure HTML5 designer/editor (like Dreamweaver) or it is only for Windows 8 app development?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that blend is primarily for windows 8 app development

Stay away from WYSISWYG editors.. they only create hassle in the long run. I suggest software by jetbrains. They have excellent PHP / ASP editors with great debuggers and html 5/ css validators

Comment: Thanks. When you say WYSISWYG editors create hassle in long run, can you please list down any specific points.

Comment: Out dated markup techniques, horrible style sheets. Most WYSIWYG editors will render different than the browser.  I use firebug and a text editor (php storm). I can edit live!

Comment: I can also edit live with Chrome + Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials, and I even have auto LESS/SASS compilation and minification on the fly.